What is the difference between overflow Hidden and Visible
This is my HTML code.


body {
    text-align: center;
}

ul {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #1d6b0d;
    list-style-type: none;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 0.5rem;
}
<h3>HTML Horizontal Unordered List</h3>

<ul>
    <li><a href="#course">Course</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Blog">Blogs</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="#Content">Content</a>
    </li>
</ul>



This is the output.
I changed overflow to visible.
Now this is the output.
According to what I studied, overflow:visible must make the overflowed content visible. But,
here in my code, visible is making the list disappear. hidden is making the list visible. I tried asking AI, but did not get any satisfactory answer.
Why is overflow:hidden making the list visible?

It's not visible because it has no height

The overflow property controls what happens to content that is too large to fit within its container. The most common values are:
overflow: visible: The overflowed content is not clipped and will be visible outside the element's box. This is the default value.
overflow: hidden:  The overflowed content is clipped and hidden from view. Anything outside the element’s box will not be displayed.

The characters are there when you set overflow visible only they are white so not seen against the 'normal' white background. Try setting their color to black and you will see them.

By default, the overflow of elements is set to visible. When you use overflow: hidden; the element disappears from view but is not removed.
However, when you use the float property, you may encounter many problems because float itself changes the element’s height, width, and display properties to move the element across the container. Therefore, you should avoid using the float property. If you do use it, remember to set display: flex; (or display: table;) on the parent element <ul>.
I highly recommend that you stop using float and switch to Flexbox instead.

This doesn't explain the phenomenon described in the question.

If you don't understand something, it doesn't mean that others don't either.
check these links:
https://www.w3.org/TR/css-page-floats-3/
https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp

I don’t think either of those references tackles the overflow settings in the parent, which is what this question is about. This reference describes the phenomenon: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#block-root-margin

The topic is not about logic at all, "What is the difference between overflow Hidden and Visible" and this question is answered.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
